# Mapping synset ids from older version of Wordnet

Tags: nltk, wordnet

How do I map synsets offsets of older versions of Wordnet (1.6 to be specific) to the current version (3.0), preferably using NLTK?

For example, in 1.6, wrath has the offset 5588321, while 3.0 gives 7516905 for the same.

My primary need for this was to implement Wordnet-Affect http://wndomains.fbk.eu/wnaffect.html
which uses version 1.6 unfortunately.

I did manage to find a repository at https://github.com/clemtoy/WNAffect thanks to which I could successfully use the database that did offer a solution to the problem for the requirements that using Wordnet affect had, but it did not map synsets to achieve it.

Getting offset in Wordnet 3.0, nltk

```
wn.synset('wrath.n.01').offset()
7516905
```

EDIT:

Getting the name of a synset from its id for Wordnet 1.6 would serve as well.

EDIT2:

Here is how the information is exactly stored. This is a small subset -

```
<noun-syn id="n#05588321" categ="wrath"/>
<noun-syn id="n#05576115" categ="worship"/>
<noun-syn id="n#05600844" categ="world-weariness"/>
<noun-syn id="n#05582577" categ="wonder"/>
<noun-syn id="n#05600968" categ="woe"/>
<noun-syn id="n#05579569" categ="withdrawal"/>
<noun-syn id="n#05604301" categ="weight"/>
<noun-syn id="n#05601315" categ="weepiness"/>
<noun-syn id="n#05574157" categ="weakness"/>
<noun-syn id="n#05611809" categ="warpath"/>
```

These ids are all outdate WN1.6 ids

Comment: Interesting question. Can you give more information about the situation, including examples of corresponding synsets, and the use you have made of them that makes a mapping necessary? Few people are likely to have two versions of wordnet lying around, so you're far more likely to get help if you provide all the necessary information.

Comment: I have added some details :)

Comment: That's a start, but I've casually used wordnet in the nltk and I've never heard of an "offset". Give usable code! Remember, the point is to make it possible for people to help you who do not have wordnet-affect (whatever that is) installed.

Comment: Hmm but my question is not necessarily related to wordnet-affect. I'll add code that gives the offset for the current wordnet but beyond that, I don't see any code that I can add here given my question.

Comment: What do you need the offset for? Why do you even care what it was before, why is it not enough to match synsets by name, and what are you trying to accomplish by "matching" between versions anyway? Nobody can help you solve your problem if you can't state your goals comprehensibly.

Comment: The reason I need the offsets is because Wordnet-affect uses offsets to identify synsets - values which have since changed. My question is pretty clear - I want to map synset ids from older versions to the current one. That is my goal, for the purpose of this question. I would also settle for a way to get the name of a synset from its id for Wordnet 1.6. That would serve as well, but I don't see a way to do it. You seem to have gotten really aggressive really fast.

Comment: Apologies if that sounded aggressive, I assure you I have no stake in this. Since you don't find my questions helpful, I'll stop pestering you. Good luck.

Comment: @alexis I don't mind the questions. I realised I could have been clearer in elaborating my actual need for the offsets. I hope the above comment did that. If you don't think so, please tell me why - I'm open to any solution. - The fact is that I have been given only the offset values and not the names to accompany them.

Comment: You can judge the success of your question by the answers you get.

Comment: Maybe that's because it's a difficult question to answer? I already told you I have my information in the form of wordnet 1.6 offset values and nothing else. If you have any other way around this, you are free to enlighten me. I've edited the question to make it more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody has suggested a shortcut, sounds like you need to do it the obvious way: Fire up an 1.6 Wordnet and convert offsets to synsets yourself. You'll find an official version 1.6 download of Wordnet on [this page.](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/download/old-versions/)

I've got no idea how hard they tried to maintain backward compatibility, but hopefully `wrath.n.01` is more or less the same thing in all versions of Wordnet. I'm guessing that some senses were split up into two or more synsets  between versions, and maybe even the reverse happens occasionally. In such cases there won't be such a thing as an exact counterpart of the original synset. Whether that's a problem for you is for you to decide.